# How can I change my MS DOS to window 7?

Tags: windows-7

today I buied new lenovo and it had MS DOS so I wanna use window 7 in lenovo

How can i change to window 7 from default MS DOS window ?

please help me

Comment: You don't have MS DOS installed. If you want to know how to install Windows 7, it's described in detail in the installation guide that comes with it.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Some new laptops *do* come with FreeDOS.

Comment: @grawity: Yeah, that has actually come up on [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926167#7926167). However, I did not see how that is relevant to the process of installing Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

If it is actually running the MS-DOS OS, then put in the Windows 7 disk (or USB) and boot off that to install Windows 7.

I very highly doubt it is actually running MS-DOS though, especially if you just bought it, just make sure you aren't it getting mixed up with command prompt.

Comment: yes sure , I bought lenovo with MS DOS because it is too cheap for me . After that I wanna use Window 7 in that lenovo . Does it need to edit boot setting to install window 7 ?

Comment: You will need to set the boot device as first in the BIOS if that's what you mean?

Comment: I believe on Lenovo systems you can press F12 at the initial BIOS screen to choose what device to boot from.

Comment: Before press F12 , Can I input my window 7 DVD to DVD drive ?    brother , If you know tutorials movie in youtube or others . I wanna see it , please point to me

Comment: Does it same with normal installation window 7 ?

Comment: Just put the disk in, if you miss the bios just reboot and press F12 as @ultrasawblade suggested, set either the CD drive or USB (whichever you are booting off) as the first device to boot from, and run through the install :)

Comment: No worries buddy :)

Comment: @BaliC: Some new laptops *do* come with FreeDOS (although not MS-DOS).

Comment: @grawity Ah right, I didn't know that, that might be it!